# How to filter only 1 matching element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 apples in array. Filter method deletes all apples. Is there a way to delete only 1 of them.

```
var box = ['banana', 'apple', 'apple']
```

Output that I'm expectig:

```
box.filter((a) => a !== 'apple') => ['banana', 'apple']
```

Comment: Are you asking for a function that deletes duplicates? Did you search? There are many Q&A about that already....

Comment: @trincot - I don't read it that way, but I can see how someone would. Taner - What result would you expect on `["banana", "apple", "pear", "apple", "orange", "apple"]`?

Comment: The OP should answer that.

Comment: If there are three `"apples"` in the array should it still only return one?

Comment: The question means that `only one element should be removed`. I do not know why the question was closed. I am waiting for @Taner for explanation.

Comment: That isn't clear @wittgenstein. In the example case removing one also has the effect of making it unique.

Comment: @ Taner - Stack Overflow is a **very** active place, even on the weekend. When you post a question (or an answer), *stick around* for a few minutes so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments.

Comment: Either way, it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing built-in, no. You can remember whether you've seen it and always return `true` afterward:

```js
const box = ["banana", "apple", "apple"];

let seenApple = false;
const filtered = box.filter((a) => {
    if (seenApple) {
        return true;
    }
    seenApple = a === "apple";
    return !seenApple;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Alternatively you could find the index of the first `apple`:

```
const appleIndex = box.findIndex(a => a === "apple");
```

...and then either `filter` by that index:

```
const filtered = box.filter((entry, index) => index !== appleIndex);
```

...or use `splice` to modify the array in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to remove duplicates?
If you just want an array with unique elements, you can do something like this

```
var unique_arr = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

Comment: *"...to delete only 1 of them..."* doesn't sound like "remove duplicates" to me. But if so, yes, this is good enough for a small array. Lots of repeated searching, though, so scales not very well.

Comment: This is blowing my mind right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure with another variable for overriding the condition.

```js
const
    box = ['banana', 'apple', 'apple'],
    result = box.filter(
        (found => a => a !== 'apple' || found || !(found = true))
        (false)
    );

console.log(result);
```